# selected_real_kind in gfortran and code::blocks

Tags: fortran, codeblocks, gfortran

I try to compile a program

```
program test

    integer,parameter :: p6 = selected_real_kind(6)

end program test
```

using gfortran and code::blocks. But i recieve an error message in build log window:

```
f951.exe: internal compiler error: Illegal instruction
libbacktrace could not find executable to open
Please submit a full bug report,
with preprocessed source if appropriate.
See <http://gcc.gnu.org/bugs.html> for instructions.
Process terminated with status 1 (0 minute(s), 0 second(s))
0 error(s), 0 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 0 second(s))
```

What is wrong with my code or settings? Thanks for any help!

Comment: Which gfortran is that? Where did you get that and what is the version?

Comment: I downloaded gfortran from https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/GFortranBinaries#Windows (dated 2014-06-29)

Answer (score 0):

So, it looks like OP is currently using a rather old build of a development version, thus, I'm not surprised OP have an internal compiler error. From my experience I recommend builds from MinGW-w64, say mingw-builds, which can be downloaded from [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw-w64/files/Toolchains%20targetting%20Win32/Personal%20Builds/mingw-builds/) (generate binaries for 32-bit Windows) or [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw-w64/files/Toolchains%20targetting%20Win64/Personal%20Builds/mingw-builds/) (generate binaries for 64-bit Windows).

There are few different variants of the mingw-builds. For 32-bit case I recommend to go with [POSIX threads & DWARF exception handling variant](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw-w64/files/Toolchains%20targetting%20Win32/Personal%20Builds/mingw-builds/5.1.0/threads-posix/dwarf/), while for 64-bit case - [POSIX threads & SEH exception handling variant](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw-w64/files/Toolchains%20targetting%20Win64/Personal%20Builds/mingw-builds/5.1.0/threads-posix/seh/).

P.S. Currently I would not recommend GCC 5 for working with a large code base, since I experienced few internal compiler errors with it. GCC 4.9.2 is a much safer bet right now.

Comment: Thanks. I'll try to install the build you recommend.